# Extract dollar sign and amount from string using -match

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm matching a string:

```
"this transaction will cost $600" -match "\`$ \d{1,3}"
```

I want `matches[0]` to match only the value and `$` sign substring:

```
$600
```

what am I missing?

Comment: 'this transaction will cost $600' -match '$'

Comment: not the best edit either, replacing `$ with \\`$ :D great job ariel

Comment: Have you googled anything to find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

not the best way i guess

```
$string = 'this transaction will cost $600'

$string -match 'will cost \$(?<content>.*)'

"In `$: $($matches['content'])"
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise using a greedy modifier. While is works in this case it wont always be at the end of the string. `\d*` would at least be a little better.

Comment: whats ta greedey thingie

Comment: `.*` < in regex this is a greedy quantifier that matches as many characters that it can. Your regex would  not work if the string was: "'this transaction will cost $600. I hope you are OK with that."

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here. First is with the input string. You have a dollar sign followed by alphanumerics. PowerShell is going to try and expand that string with the variable `$600`. Presumably that does not exist and will, in your case, come back null. Type in just the string to see what I mean.

```
PS C:\Users\stuff> "this transaction will cost $600"
this transaction will cost
```

Second is that you have a space after your dollar in your regex. That will attempt to match something like "$ 600" which you don't have. Need to tighten that up.

```
PS C:\Users\stuff> 'this transaction will cost $600' -match "\$\d{1,3}"
True

PS C:\Users\stuff> $Matches[0]
$600
```

The dollar sign in the regex does not need to be escaped in this case but having the single quotes prevents tomfoolery. Be careful if you actually want variables to expand there though. You will need to put back in double quotes or use something like the format operator.